# Why does DispatchWorkItem notify crash?

Tags: swift, queue, grand-central-dispatch, swift4, dispatchworkitem

I've just started to learn a little bit more about Grand Central Dispatch in the Swift programming language.

I followed a tutorial online to better understand GCD and tried various examples of usage...

in the section about Work Item I wrote the following code :

```
func useWorkItem() {
    var value = 10
    let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        value += 5
    }

    workItem.perform()
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
    queue.async(execute: workItem)

    workItem.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("value = ", value)
    }
}
```

the code basically perform the workItem in two different queues (the main and global queue) and when the work item finish running in both queues I get the result.

the output of the code above is : 20.

when I tried to manipulate the code a little bit and added another Queue to the mix and ran the same workItem with the same `qos` as the global queue (`.utility`), like so :

```
 func useWorkItem() {
    var value = 10
    let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        value += 5
    }

    workItem.perform()
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
    queue.async(execute: workItem)

    let que = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.delayqueue1", qos: .utility)
    que.async(execute: workItem)

    workItem.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("value = ", value)
    }
}
```

the app crashes.

but when I change the order of the commands so I move the `workItem.notify` method to the beginning of the method, the app works and give me correct output which is 25 :

```
func useWorkItem() {
    var value = 10
    let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        value += 5
    }

    workItem.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("value = ", value)
    }

    workItem.perform()
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
    queue.async(execute: workItem)
    let que = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.delayqueue1", qos: .utility)
    que.async(execute: workItem)
}
```

can anyone please help understand how the `.notify()` method really works ?
and why the order of the commands made a difference ?

thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Two things: First, if the app crashes, you might want to share the details of the crash. (As an aside, I'm unable to reproduce the crash, but there is stuff here that is crash-worthy. Lol.) Also, you shared a somewhat dubious example from some unnamed tutorial. You might want to share a link to the tutorial so we understand what the author's intent was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first example you share (which I gather is directly from the tutorial) is not well written for a couple of reasons:

1. It's updating a variable from multiple threads. That is an inherently non thread-safe process. It turns out that for reasons not worth outlining here, it's not technically an issue in the author's original example, but it is a very fragile design, illustrated by the non-thread-safe behavior quickly manifested in your subsequent examples.

   One should always [synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) access to a variable if manipulating it from multiple threads. You can use a dedicated serial queue for this, a `NSLock`, reader-writer pattern, or other patterns. While I'd often use another GCD queue for the synchronization, I think that's going to be confusing when we're focusing on the GCD behavior of `DispatchWorkItem` on various queues, so in my example below, I'll use `NSLock` to synchronize access, calling `lock()` before I try to use `value` and `unlock` when I'm done.
2. You say that first example displays "20". That's a mere accident of timing. If you change it to say ...

   ```
   let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
       os_log("starting")
       Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
       value += 5
       os_log("done")
   }
   ```

   ... then it will likely say "15", not "20" because you'll see the `notify` for the `workItem.perform()` before the `async` call to the global queue is done. Now, you'd never use `sleep` in real apps, but I put it in to illustrate the timing issues.

   Bottom line, the `notify` on a `DispatchWorkItem` happens when the dispatch work item is first completed and it won't wait for the subsequent invocations of it. This code entails what is called a "race condition" between your `notify` block and the call you dispatched to that global queue and you're not assured which will run first.
3. Personally, even setting aside the race conditions and the inherently non thread-safe behavior of mutating some variable from multiple threads, I'd advise against invoking the same `DispatchWorkItem` multiple times, at least in conjunction with `notify` on that work item.
4. If you want to do a notification when everything is done, you should use a `DispatchGroup`, not a `notify` on the individual `DispatchWorkItem`.

Pulling this all together, you get something like:

```
import os.log

var value = 10
let lock = NSLock()   // a lock to synchronize our access to `value`

func notifyExperiment() {
    // rather than using `DispatchWorkItem`, a reference type, and invoking it multiple times,
    // let's just define some closure or function to run some task

    func performTask(message: String) {
        os_log("starting %@", message)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)    // we wouldn't do this in production app, but lets do it here for pedagogic purposes, slowing it down enough so we can see what's going on
        lock.lock()
        value += 5
        lock.unlock()
        os_log("done %@", message)
    }

    // create a dispatch group to keep track of when these tasks are done

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    // let's enter the group so that we don't have race condition between dispatching tasks
    // to the queues and our notify process

    group.enter()

    // define what notification will be done when the task is done

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.lock.lock()
        os_log("value = %d", self.value)
        self.lock.unlock()
    }

    // Let's run our task once on the global queue

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async(group: group) {
        performTask(message: "from global queue")
    }

    // Let's run our task also on a custom queue

    let customQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.delayqueue1", qos: .utility)
    customQueue.async(group: group) {
        performTask(message: "from custom queue")
    }

    // Now let's leave the group, resolving our `enter` at the top, allowing the `notify` block
    // to run iff (a) all `enter` calls are balanced with `leave` calls; and (b) once the `async(group:)`
    // calls are done.

    group.leave()
}
```

Comment: thank you, great explanation... I think I understand it a little bit better now 